# Android ContentResolver query sometimes not starting ContentProvider process

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

I have been implementing my own custom content provider in an app A and want to query its database from a separate app B that calls ContentResolver.query(...) using the appropriate custom URI defined in A.

All goes well when A has been running just before I launch B (thus A's process still  running in the background).

However when I kill A's process, then B fails to query A's database! I thought querying a content provider would automatically start its process so the data can be retrieved. Am I missing something?

Some clarifications:

- I properly set up the content provider. There is no problem with misspellings in the authority string, no problem with permissions, the provider is properly declared in A's manifest with the proper name, authorities, exported and enabled. I went over about any example I could find about custom content providers to absolutely get it right.
- The package manager tells me the provider is properly registered in the system (even when its process is not running). I verified that using 
  `List<PackageInfo> info = context.getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PROVIDERS);`
- When B fails to query A's provider, logcat's error message is 
  `E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.example.provider.MyProvider`
  Neither the constructor nor the onCreate method of A's provider is being called in that case.
- I tried other query methods using a ContentProviderClient, a CursorLoader, direct query from adb; the behaviour is always the same.
- I have even created a third app C with a simplistic test content provider (as A is a bit more complex); still the same problem.
- The problem occurs only when I use my real device, not when I use an emulator (even using the exact same Android version). I am using an Alcatel OneTouch Idol 3, model number 6045Y, running Android 5.0.2, Kernel version 3.10.49.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: It's possible that by "killing" A's process you are actually putting it in a stopped state where the system will not launch any of its components unless the user explicitly does so. Try adding a BroadcastReceiver to A, stop A's process, and attempt to send a broadcast Intent from B that would normally be received by A. Let us know how that works out.

Comment: Thanks Karakuri! I just implemented what you suggested (the onReceive() method in A creates a log message and also sends a notification). The behavior is the same again: a broadcast from App B is received by A exactly in all cases where A's content provider can be queried by B succesfully.

Comment: By the way, the problem does not just occur when I kill the process by hand, but also when, for example I let the device sleep for a while and then wake it up and start App B right away (without starting A by hand before that).

Comment: That's strange... Is A doing any periodic work in the background that might crash? I had almost the exact same problem once before, where components in my app wouldn't start after the phone sat overnight. The reason was something in my app would crash in the background, then would get started again later by a periodic mechanism, crash again, etc, until the OS decided to mark my process as bad and refuse to start any of my app's components. I only discovered it by looking back through my logcat from overnight.

Comment: No, A is not doing any background work. Also, the time where the content provider query stops working seems to be pretty much random. Once it does not work, it never works again until A has been put in the foreground again.

Comment: @mkoe: did you get any resolution on it yet ?

Comment: Unfortunately not, thanks for asking. If you have any idea, please tell me. At this point, I might believe its a bug in the Android implementation on my particular phone model. However, now I am afraid to use ContentProviders in my Apps in general, as the problem could exist on other phones as well.